# how to prevent in mongodb that keys are auto arranged in ascending in object type while insert/update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my case i have schema as mentioned below. in this schema values key has an object with dynamic key:value pairs. while i am inserting/updating using this schema the sequence of my key value pair are changed to acceding. How can i prevent this.??

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
    formName: String
    values: Object
})
```

example...
my data to insert/update is... and i want to store it in same sequence.

```
{
   formName: "my Form",
   values: {
        textBox1:"Value1",
        dropdown1:"Value2",
        textBox2:"Value3",
   }
}
```

but the data is stored in below given sequence..

```
{
   formName: "my Form",
   values: {
        dropdown1:"Value2",
        textBox1:"Value1",
        textBox2:"Value3",
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use an array for that.

Instead of inserting/updating values via Object, it would be better to store key and value in array.

```
{
   formName: "my Form",
   keys: ["textBox1","dropdown1","textBox2"],
   values: ["value1","value2","value3"]
}
```